How do I get a try / exception statement to continue?
I need this to rerun the initial inpput question if it gets a value that is unacceptable.
     try:
    hours = float(input("Please enter your hours worked: "))
    if hours < 1 :
        print("Please enter a value greater than 0 ")
        #continue isn't working, figure out how to loop back to top instead
                    #temporary placeholder fix  
        hours= int(input("Please enter your hours worked: "))
#if a non-numerical value is entered
except:
    print("Please enter a numerical value greater than 0")
       #temporary placeholder fix  
            hours= int(input("Please enter your hours worked: "))

I tried usisng a continue statement, but it doesn't work with this code. How can I get the code to ask the user for input again if the input fails the if statement or triggers the except statement? I'm really new at this.

Please format your code correctly. Indentation is important in Python.

can you try it this way. While loop will continue until its greater than 0
try:
    hours = float(input("Please enter your hours worked: "))
    while hours< 1 :
        print("Please enter a value greater than 0 ")
        #continue isn't working, figure out how to loop back to top instead
        #temporary placeholder fix  
        hours= int(input("Please enter your hours worked: "))
        #if a non-numerical value is entered
except:
    print("error occured")
    


This will stop as soon as the user inputs a non-integer which moots the point of the try-except.
